# Whether a dice game is profitable in the long run

Tags: probability, expected-value, dice

As part of a course, I came across this question

"A player is offered to play against a dealer who rolls 6 dice simultaneously. If there's a 'street' (each of the numbers from $1$ to $6$ appears on each of the dice), then the dealer wins $60\$$, else, the player wins $1\$$. Is this game profitable in the long run?"

For this, I tried writing the expression for the expected value after $n$ plays and tried to examine the expression in the limit, and whether it is always positive. What I got is the following

$$E(n,p) = \sum_{i=0}^n (n-61i){n \choose i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$$

Where $p$ is the probability of a street occuring (which would be $\frac{6!}{6^6}$)

I am stuck on this expression, don't know how to make any conclusions from this. Another interesting side note is to quantify the effect of changing the winning/losing amounts on $E$, to design a game where it is break even in the long run

Edit - corrected the probability of obtaining a street, forgot to account for permutations

I derived the expression by considering the cases of $i$ losses and $(n-i)$ wins in $n$ trials and summing over $i$ weighted with the return from each possible trial

Comment: By the way, the probability of a "street" occuring, I believe, is $\frac{6!}{6^6}$. Explanation: https://socratic.org/questions/a-six-sided-die-is-rolled-six-times-what-is-the-probability-that-each-side-appea

Comment: Also, I don't understand how you came up with the sum expression. If you know the probability $p$, shouldn't the expected value of a single round be just
$$
\mathbb{E} = p\underbrace{(-60)}_{\text{loss}} + (1-p)\underbrace{(1)}_{\text{win}}
$$

Comment: Fixed in the edit

Comment: @MattiP. yeah, that's right for one round. My expression is for $n$ rounds. If you put $n=1$ in the expression, it reduces to what you've typed

Comment: But the expected value does not change when you have multiple rounds, does it?

Comment: I see that you wanted to calculate something like a binomial distribution, in the sum expression. But what is the factor $(n-61i)$ ?

Comment: If the expectation for one round is $-60p + (1 - p)$ then the expectation of $n$ rounds should be $\sum_{i = 1}^n -60p + (1 - p) = -60np + (1 - p)n = -61pn + n$ by linearity of expectation.

Comment: So suppose I have played the game $n$ times, and have $i$ losses and $(n-i)$ wins. Then the expected value would be $(n-i- 60i) * p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$?

Comment: @MattiP. The $(n-61i)$ would be the net value I earn for that particular case. So the expectation would be the sum of value earned into the probability of that case occuring, no?

Comment: Find the expectation for one round and then use linearity of expectation for finding the expectation for $n$ rounds. Anyway, it will $n$ times the expectation for one round so the info for one round is enough already to anwer the question whether the game is profitable or not.

Comment: But why are the two not equal?

Comment: If you have $i$ losses and $n-i$ wins, surely the result (money that you have in the end) is
$$
i(-60) + (n-i)(1)
$$
But the **probability** of $i$ losses and $n-i$ wins is
$$
{n \choose i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i}
$$

Comment: Okay, so the expectation should be the summation of result into probability, $$\sum_i(n-61i)*{n \choose i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$$

Comment: And this would reduce to $n(1-61p)$? It should if the linearity of expectation is to hold, no?

Comment: yes it sounds like you are using the simple fact that $1 = 1^n = (p + (1-p))^n = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$. But as others have pointed out, it's not clear why you want to write it in this way!